# Likelihood of passing HSV1 when no sores are present

Tags: epidemiology, herpes, herpes-simplex

### Prior research:

WHO [Says](https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/herpes-simplex-virus)

- Both HSV-1 and HSV-2 are most contagious when sores are present, **but can also be transmitted when no symptoms are felt or visible.**

### Question:

My problem is I am looking for data how much transmissible is HSV1 **when no symptoms are visible**, like: 10% of the time? 90%? The quote from WHO is not sufficiently informative.

Comment: I asked google your question and [this](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/genital-herpes-beyond-the-basics/print#:~:text=But%20it%20is%20still%20possible,in%2010%20percent%20of%20couples.) was the very first hit. Does it not answer your question? If not, then please [edit] your question to include what you research has found. Prior research is a requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

As [Carey Gregory](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/users/805/carey-gregory) notes in a [comment](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/likelihood-of-passing-hsv1-when-no-sores-are-present#comment60314_31300), [the article on UpToDate](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/genital-herpes-beyond-the-basics) about this subject reports some useful information:

> [I]t is still possible to spread the infection even when no ulcers are present.
>
> One study examined rates of genital herpes transmission in heterosexual couples when only one partner was initially infected [1]. Over one year, the virus was transmitted to the other partner in 10 percent of couples. In 70 percent of cases, infection occurred at a time when there were no symptoms.

[1] Mertz et al 2019. PMID [1309413](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1309413/).

Comment: That study is not related it is about passing genital herpes, not HSV1

Comment: Also OP was interested in *oro-genital* HSV-1 transmission in this question, but I can't edit it anymore because I lost access to account

Comment: There are no restrictions on the account and no reason you can't edit the question, so if you've lost the password just do the forgotten password procedure.